# Getting UID Reference for Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a reference to a document's UID so I can use the document elsewhere in my project by it's UID. As per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data), I'm doing the following with AngularFire2 (v5):

```
var ref= this.afs.collection(placeToAdd).doc();
```

This gives me the following error: *"Expected 1 arguments but got 0"*. It wants me to put an argument in the doc() method. So instead, I do:

```
var ref= this.afs.collection(placeToAdd).doc(thing);
```

then I set my Firebase object:

```
ref.set({
        item1: 'value 1',
        item2: 'value 2',
        item3: 'value 3'
      });
```

How do I get the ref's Firestore-generated UID now?

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out:

```
let newUID = this.afs.createId();
```

Then create this firestore object at the location of newUID:

```
var ref= this.afs.collection(placeToAdd).doc(thing);
```

Answer (score 4):

To clarify: there is two ways of inserting data in firestore. One recieves the uid from you.

```
db.collection(collection).doc(uid).set(data);
```

The other is adding the thocument but letting firestore generate the uid for you.

```
db.collection(collection).add(documentData)
.then(ref => {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", ref.id);
});
```

It's important to note that both set and add return a promise of document ref, in case you want to use it and for error handling.

[The documentation covers this in much more detail.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)